# AngularJs and tabset

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-tabset

I have a tabset with 3 tabs:

```
<tabset>
    <tab heading="Tab1" active="activeTab1">
        ...
    </tab>
    <tab heading="Tab2" active="activeTab2" select="tabTab2()">
        ...
        <div id="newMap" class="col-sm-12" style="height: 400px;"></div>
        ...
    </tab>
    <tab heading="Tab3" active="activeTab3" select="tabTab3()">
        ...
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

On the controller:

```
$scope.tabTab2 = function()
{
   console.log("tab2");
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("newMap"), mapOptions);
}

$scope.tabTab3 = function()
{
   console.log("tab3");
}
```

So, I have 2 questions related to this code.

First: if `activeTab2` is set to `true`, the function `tabTab2` will run twice (same thing regarding the Tab3). Why is that? If I then select tab1 and get back to the tab2 it will run only once...

Second: I'm trying to use the google.maps inside the div `newMap` but it's throwing the error `Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null` and the `null` element is the `document.getElementById("newMap")`. Once again, why is that?

If I set `activeTab2` to `false` and `activeTab1` to true, and then click on the tab2, it works fine. The problem is only when its active on the begginning...

---------  EDIT  -------------

here's the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4jLl3U?p=preview)

If you set the activeTab1 to TRUE, it works, if you set to FALSE (and the activeTab2 sets to TRUE) it doesn't work.

On reply to maurycy, the names tabTab1... are ONLY to Stackoverflow question...

----- EDIT2 -------

plunker url updated

----- EDIT3 -------

So, just realized that the problem is the fact that the tab is runnning twice the function on the `select`. If you change the plunker to

```
$scope.tabTab2 = function()
{
  console.log("Tab2");
  console.log(document.getElementById("newMap"));
}
```

and the `activeTab` to TRUE, the console will show

```
Tab2
null
Tab2
<div id="newMap" class="col-sm-12" style="height: 400px;"></div>
```

So, the first time the function runs the element doesn't exist, but on the second it does...

Comment: Please add a plunker or fiddle my friend.

Comment: `tabTab2` and `tabTab3` (terrible names BTW) will run whenever html partial is evaluated i.e. during `$digest()` cycle, also `$digest` will run when model changes any case of `$scope.something = somethingelse` From personal experience - avoid functions in partials, with big projects you can have performance issues

Comment: I guess plunker is down :-(

Comment: if both functions will run whenever html partial is evaluated, why only run when the corresponding TAB is active? according to you, it would always run...

Comment: I've checked the bootstrap sourcode and documentation since I wasn't sure what does the select attribute does, from documentation: `select() (Defaults: null) : An optional expression called when tab is activated.` ok so it's not evaluated like others functions in partials, i'll play around with your plunk to get some answers